# Is every Baire space Cech-complete?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I can't think of any example of a topological space satisfying the Baire Category Theorem which is not Cech-complete. (A space is *Cech-complete* if it is a Tychonoff space and if it is a $G_\delta$ subset of its Stone-Cech compactification, or equivalently of any other compactification). There isn't even an example of one in $\pi$-base. However, it's very well known every Cech-complete space is Baire, and I've never seen it mentioned that the reverse is true as well.

Are these properties equivalent? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: There are metrisable but not completely metrisable Baire spaces: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150472/completely-metrizable-space-and-baire-theorem

Comment: Very good, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{N}^{\omega_1}$ is Baire (as any product of Čech-complete spaces is, Engelking 3.9.J(e), due to Oxtoby or Bourbaki), but it is not a $k$-space (see Engelking 3.3.E(a)) so not Cech-complete.

A metrisable example: $X = \mathbb{Q}\times \{0\} \cup \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ (subspace topology) is Baire as $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$ is open and dense and Baire (as a locally compact space, e.g.).
But $X$ cannot be Čech-complete as the closed subset $\mathbb{Q} \times \{0\} \simeq \mathbb{Q}$ would be Čech-complete (the class is closed under closed subsets and $G_\delta$ subsets) which it is not.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma...you are one of the kings of general topology  in MSE..;)

Comment: I still like my old field... and glad to help @MariosGretsas

Comment: @HennoBrandsma..I also love this field and i want to master it (when i say master ,maybe it sounds naive..i mean to become very good at it)because it will help me in analysis..Now that i found you,i would like your opinion about something if you have the time of course..:)

Comment: @MariosGretsas read good topology books, lots of papers and go to conferences for 6 years or so...

Comment: Is it a good move to take a book and solve it all?..At my level i was thinking to read and solve topology without tears..Munkres would be very difficult for me at this level i am

Comment: @MariosGretsas practice is very good. Reading good exposition too.

Comment: Can you suggest some books?

Comment: Thank you! This is quite counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: @MariosGretsas If Munkres is too hard, topology without tears is fine,and freely available. http://at.yorku.ca/i/a/a/b/23.htm is also basic and accessible.

Comment: Ok.. thank you for the conversation and your time..:)